# DevOps Pipeline Not Triggering from Bitbucket

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, bitbucket

I've tried to setup a DevOps pipeline to trigger from BitBucket but it won't auto-trigger. Running it manually works fine. As far as I can tell, everything is setup correctly and I'm not sure how to debug further.

1. My pipeline is not overriding the trigger
   [image: Pipeline override]
2. My pipeline yaml is set to trigger on multiple branches
   [image: yaml]
3. I'm an admin for the bitbucket repo and I can see a webhook is added when I create the pipeline
   [image: webhook]

[image: webhook]

The request history from bitbucket shows that ADO returns a 200 call after a push
[image: push success]

But nothing is triggered in ADO.

There's a few oddities I've noticed in ADO, not sure if they are related. When I edit the pipeline and look at Triggers->YAML it says "Some settings need attention" although none of the settings are showing that they need attention
[image: pipeline yaml]

Also, if I go to my Devops Project Settings->Service Connections and select the BitBucket connection, Edit and try to Authorize I get an error about a refresh token

[image: Auth]

I don't see anywhere to debug further in ADO. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you actually run the pipeline? Your trigger section looks weird -- each entry should start with a dash, so `- dev`, `- test`, etc. Also, your `pr` trigger is set to trigger on a branch named `none`, disabling it would be `pr: none`

Comment: Wow, now I feel stupid. That was the problem. Do you want to put it as an answer and I'll mark it as correct? The builds would manually run for what it's worth.

Comment: Sure. In the future, please post things like YAML documents and error messages as text, not screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The triggers are incorrectly specified.

```
trigger:
  - dev
    test
    master
```

should be

```
trigger:
  - dev
  - test
  - master
```

Also, the PR section is currently designed to trigger on a branch named `none`:

```
pr:
  - none
```

The correct syntax to disable PR validation would be

```
pr: none
```